# Set multilanguage validation error message asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm trying to set message for attribute this way in view model

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = nameof(Form.Required), ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Form))]
```

So i have my Form.resx file with Required key. I use PublicResXFileCodeGenerator tool and embedded resource type for resource file. I also have other files named form.*culture*.resx.

I'm also use this to set culture (current culture is "en" too now)

```
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en");
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(currentCulture);
```

at custom filter attribute.
The problem is that when I try to sumbit my form with empty field, i'm receiving the same message (in Russian).

Comment: what is 'currentCulture' in the second row?

Comment: @pwrigshihanomoronimo user can set his prefed language (as cookie) so i receive it via cookie and set my U Iculture

Comment: it should be enough to change language of localization, maybe something wrong with attribute filter usage etc.

Comment: also maybe language of localization does not match to culture name so it uses Russian language as a fallback

Comment: @pwrigshihanomoronimo it works with everything else in my project, 99% of text is set in resource files, so i think thats not the reason